# How to read ringtone from ringtone preferences

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-preferences

i tried below code. But i'm not able to read the ring tone from ringtone preferences.

```
        <RingtonePreference 
            android:title="@string/RING_TONE_SETTING" 
            android:summary="@string/RING_TONE_SETTING_DESCRIPTION" 
            android:ringtoneType="notification"
            android:showSilent="true"
            android:showDefault="true"
            android:key="prefnotificationTone"/>
```

This is how i'm reading,

```
 SharedPreferences preference = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    String strRingtonePreference = preference.getString("prefnotificationTone", "DEFAULT_SOUND");        

    Uri notification = Uri.parse(strRingtonePreference);

    mMPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), notification);
    mMPlayer.start();
```

I'm getting DEFAULT_SOUND always.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following attribute to the preference in XML:

```
android:persistent="true"
```

Comment: Is the preference activity / fragment also using the default  shared preferences?

Comment: Yes, and in that fragment do you have a line similar to this? `getPreferenceManager().setSharedPreferencesName("something");`

Comment: i'm using third party lib https://github.com/kolavar/android-support-v4-preferencefragment

Comment: I've used that too but it shouldn't affect anything. Try this: Open `Android Device Monitor` from Eclipse or Android Studio. Open tab `File Explorer` and navigate to `/data/data/<yourAppPackageName>/shared_prefs`. There you'll see all preference files used by your app. Tell me what files do you see. I suspect you write and read from different files.

Comment: Thanks for your help, i did like https://github.com/kolavar/android-support-v4-preferencefragment/issues/1. it worked thank you

Comment: You're welcome. I suggest you post your solution as an answer and accept it so others can find it easily.

Comment: Yes i'll do it, ill update my solution, do you know any answer about this question i.e http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27746707/enable-vibrate-mode-in-android-apps

Answer (score 0):

```
SharedPreferences preference = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
String strRingtonePreference = preference.getString("ring_tone_pref", "DEFAULT_SOUND");
```

You just got the uri of the ringtone above. you have to parse it to url and then get the corresponding ringtone from system.

```
defaultRingtoneUri = Uri.parse(strRingtonePreference);
    defaultRingtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(this, defaultRingtoneUri);
```

Hope this helps.